# Do we also have to save previous activity state on resource cleanup in background when using startActivityForResult()?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, startactivityforresult, onsaveinstancestate

I have a main activity which takes me to another activity using `startActivityForResult()` . The resulting activity performs a process and ultimately returns an object back to main activity . My question is:

1. If user presses home button on his android screen while he was in result activity and android cleans up the resources of my app, Do i have to only save the state of my resulting activity of or i do also have to save states of both the main and resulting activity in order to restore my app current state.
2. If i have to save the states of both the activities, how do i do that ?

P.s:
I have some data added to my main activity. I would like to restore my state for both result and main activity .

Answer (score 1):

> If user presses home button on his android screen while he was in result activity and android cleans up the resources of my app, Do i have to only save the state of my resulting activity of or i do also have to save states of both the main and resulting activity in order to restore my app current state

You do not need to trigger `onSaveInstanceState()` manually. So everything with a state which is saved by executing this method will be persisted automatically.

BUT

- not even the state of all `View`s will be saved by default. For example a `TextView` of which you changed the text will revert to the text in the layout file if you do not set the attribute `android:freezesText="true"`
- if you have some data stored in a field (property) of your `Activity`, it will be lost if you don't take steps to persist it (note this is also valid for `ViewModel`s - they survive a configuration change but they are not immortal).

Options for persisting data: if related to the `View` layer like e.g. a selected item in a `RecyclerView`, one can override `onSaveInstanceState()` and save the item id in the savedInstanceState `Bundle`. Other possibilities include writing to `SharedPreferences` and having a SQLite database. See also [Options for preserving UI state](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states) and [Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but do I have the save the state of previous activity as well ?

Comment: @Syed Hissaan - yes, for both Activitys. If you press the HOME button there will either be a saved state for both or (after some time, depends on what else happens with the device) for none

Comment: Last one.

Do we have to override onsavedInstanceState() individually in both activities, or do we have to save states of both these activities in the result activity .

Comment: You should not try to call methods of one Activity directly from another Activity. (This will cause your components to be very tightly coupled, which is not desirable because future changes will be harder to implement). As a corollary, each Activity will be responsible for saving its own state, so you have to override `onSaveInstanceState()` in both Activitys.